# What is the difference between ExecutionEnvironment and StreamExecutionEnvironment

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I am new to flink.
I noticed serveral times during the flink programming using java sometimes it is declared StreamExecutionEnvironment and sometimes ExecutionEnvironment.
What are the key differences of these 2 classes .
When to use what.

Answer (score 0):

An `ExecutionEnvironment` is what is used with the (already soft deprecated, soon to be deprecated) DataSet API. A `StreamExecutionEnvironment` is what is used with the DataStream API.

Comment: Why `ExecutionEnvironment` will be deprecated? Will `StreamExecutionEnvironment` deal with all transformations that can be done with a DataSet? I don't understand how join transformations for example that are easier for DataSet's, will all of them be supported for Streams....

Comment: @David Anderson : It is ok that ExecutionEnvironment will be  deprecated but then what  is the differrence between two.
Also if StreamExecutionEnvironment  will replace ExecutionEnvironment  then how finite source reading will happen?

Comment: The DataStream API added support running bounded workloads in BATCH execution mode in Flink 1.12. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/dev/datastream/execution_mode/.